# Disable https dotnet core 3.0 webapi

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

For dotnet core 2.x I was able to modify the program.cs file to specify ports:

```
        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:8080")
            .Build();
```

For dotnet core 3.0, the program.cs file is a little different and no matter what I do, I still get the https option.  The default program.cs file for dotnet core webapi has this:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

In the Windows command prompt, I've also tried `dotnet new webapi --no-https` in the command prompt and publishing and running the .dll it still listens on both http and https.  It looks like this option removes https from the launchSettings.json file.  I am not using Visual Studio or any IDE, only the Windows Command Prompt.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the method `Configure` in Startup.cs, remove the line

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: I've removed this line, published again, and running the .dll still shows both "Now listening on: https://localhost:5000" and "Now listening on: https://localhost:5001".  Removing this line does fix some other issues I had earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to completely disable https and close port 5001 in a Blazor and thus dotnet application by removing

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

from `Program.cs` and either adding

```
{
  ...,

  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to `appsettings.json`, or by launching the compiled binary with `--urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000` as this limits the endpoints to http only.

Comment: Yes, this is how it's done (both will be needed) and thanks for the detailed guidance to the appsettings.json structure as mine didn't have this tree to begin with and many replies simply tell you to remove the https url. I can finally debug from Visual Studio 2022 now, which kept closing my connection and crashing my .NET 6 project due to SSL issues that persisted even when trying to reinstall the dev certs with dotnet dev-certs https --clean / --trust.